# SQL-Server : How to use pivot table to get the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot-table

I have the following table

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    ColNam varchar(20),
    C1  int
)


INSERT INTO @sample
SELECT   'Admin', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  'Admin', 4  UNION ALL
SELECT   'Admin', 7     UNION ALL
SELECT   'NUser', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT  'NUser', 6  UNION ALL
SELECT   'NUser', 8  

SELECT * FROM @sample
```

I want to get the following format:

```
Admin | 1 | 4 | 7
NUser | 3 | 6 | 8

All 1,4,7,3,6,8 can be variables .
```

which method can I use to get that result? Pivot Table?
Which will be better method?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    ColNam varchar(20),
    C1  int
)


INSERT INTO @sample
SELECT   'Admin', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  'Admin', 4  UNION ALL
SELECT   'Admin', 7  

SELECT  * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  ColNam,C1
    FROM    @sample
) A
PIVOT
(
    SUM(C1) FOR C1 IN([1],[4],[7])
) PVT


--OR you might need this

SELECT   CAST(ColNam AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' | ' + CAST([1] AS VARCHAR(100) )+  ' | ' + CAST([4] AS VARCHAR(100))+  ' | ' + CAST([7] AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM 
(
    SELECT  ColNam,C1
    FROM    @sample
) A
PIVOT
(
    SUM(C1) FOR C1 IN([1],[4],[7])
) PVT
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, If I want not only 'Admin' I can have other 'Nuser' with different values. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I got the result what i want in my solution with following code:

```
-- Create Table 
CREATE TABLE tbl_sample (ColNam varchar(20),C1 int)

-- Insert Data
INSERT INTO tbl_sample
SELECT   'Admin', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  'Admin', 4  UNION ALL
SELECT   'Admin', 7 UNION ALL
SELECT   'NUser', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  'NUser', 5  UNION ALL
SELECT   'NUser', 4 

-- Because my C1 column can be variable so I create dynamic like following
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
 COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast(C1 as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast(C1 as varchar)+ ']'
  )
  FROM tbl_sample
  GROUP BY C1

-- Then Select like following  
DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT  ColNam,C1
    FROM    tbl_sample
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    MAX(C1)
    FOR C1 IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
```

I got the result I wanted. Thanks you all again.

I reference this site
[Dynamic Pivot Table Queries in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx)

Reds